# Python - writing data from a csv to new csv but row overwriten

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I have a few thousand Twitter tweets in a csv with one tweet per row (there are blank rows between each tweet). Each column of each row contains different parts of the tweet (like time, text, language, location, etc.) but not each column has the same information (ie: sometimes language appears in column AG or AH or some other one). I'm trying to clean up the data by creating a new CSV containing only English tweets and also filtering out the punctuations from each of these (English) tweets.

I'm currently stuck on how to filter out only the English tweets. This is what I have so far:

```
import csv


f = open('twitDB.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)   # csv_f is a list of lists

for row in csv_f:
    for col in row:
        if col == 'lang:"en"':
            with open('cleaned.csv', 'w') as fp:
                wr = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = ',')
                wr.writerow(row)
                wr.writerow('\n')
```

The new cleaned.csv only contains the last English tweet (of thousands) in its Row 1. I have a feeling that my code is continuously overwriting the first row of cleaned.csv and not writing each tweet onto the next row but I'm unsure how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `open('cleaned.csv', 'a')`  the `'a'` will `append` each time.. `'w'` will open and overwrite what is there each time.. This is why you are only seeing 1 row..